# MWPhotoBrowser with CocoaPod -> Build Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mwphotobrowser

I want to use [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/mwphotobrowser)in my iOS App and wanted it to add to my project. I installed CocoaPods with `sudo gem install cocoapods` (on my Mac) and created a podfile in my projects root directory with `pod init`. After that I edited the created podfile so that it looks like that:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, "7.0"

target "weshare" do

pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'

end

target "weshareTests" do

end
```

Than I ran `pod install` and after the process I opened the new created `weshare.xcworkspace`, pressed "don't unlock" at the notification that the `"Pods project" is locked for editing`, selected the `Pods` scheme and wanted to build it. But the build failed because of:

**Semantic issue**
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSUInteger, long long)' to parameter of type 'SDWebImageDow' ...

Do you know what's wrong? I did everything as the instructions said.

**EDIT:** Ok, I gave it up and chose [Method 3](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser#method-3-including-source-directly-into-your-project) to implement the library to my project, which is by the way **super easy** (just drag the items to your project, that's it). I don't know why they suggest the first two methods because they are way to weird, hard and quirky to implement, but ok.

Comment: I have never seen the `is locked for editing` notification before, any idea why is it locked? And also, can you try to use a different pod just to make sure that the problem is with your installation?

Comment: thanks for your response, have a look at my updated question. i chose another method, now it works :)